# how can i know what is the website page made off?

Tags: html, css, web, menu, navigation

Can you help me to analyze the elements of this website ?

www.hardrock.com

I want to make it similar to this.
How i can do that ? for example, the menu how i do it move when the user scrolling down ?

this is the navigation CSS code:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}

body {
background: linear-gradient(  #CCCCCC,  #CCCCCC 0%,   #999999 25%, #666666 50%, #999999 75%, #CCCCCC 100%);
}

nav {
max-width: 960px;
/* The mask-image gives us some extra fading. It is not necessary but without this, you can't face out the box-shadows. This clips our menu */
mask-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, #ffffff 25%, #ffffff 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
margin: 0 auto;
/* Using padding instead of margin for the top and bottom here will keep our box-shadow visible and not affected by the mask-image */
padding: 75px 0;
}

nav ul {
text-align: center;
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
width: 100%;
box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
padding: 20px;
font-family: "Roboto";
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
font-size: 25px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

/* Demo credits stuff */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nixie+One);
h1#author {
position: fixed;
bottom: 50px;
text-align: center;
color: #30303f;
width: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
padding: 10px 0;
font-family: "Nixie One";
text-stroke: 1px;
font-size: 30px;
text-shadow: 0 0 10px #aaaaaa;
font-family: "Roboto"
}
h1#author a {
color: #3399dd;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: any website is manly made of a hosting account, files and hard work from the developers.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't just copy and paste code from someone elses work. With that said, there's probably JavaScript involved somewhere.

I would just save the web page to your desktop and take it from there. Taking bits away until you have just what you need

Comment: I just want to know how they do the menu ! mot stealing the code

Comment: I would personally download the page and take it from there. That's how I find it best to learn, by breaking something and then fixing it

Answer (score 0):

you can know this with help of browser Extensions , search in browser's extensions "wappalyzer"

or you can visit this site for more information [wappalyzer](https://wappalyzer.com/?pk_campaign=chrome&pk_kwd=context)